# 'SSL is required but the server doesn't support it (2026)' error while making an SSL MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.7, windows-10

I'm trying to make an SSL supported connection using MySQL Workbench 6.3.9.
My OS is Windows 10 x64 and I have installed MySQL Server 5.7 x64 with OpenSSL-1.0.2L (Win64 version). 
I made a non-SSL connection without any problem but when I am trying to make an SSL connection I always get this error: '**SSL is required but the server doesn't support it (2026)**'
my.ini file contains these settings:

```
[client]
ssl-ca = "C:/vcerts/ca-cert.pem"
ssl-cert = "C:/vcerts/client-cert.pem"
ssl-key = "C:/vcerts/client-key.pem"
ssl
ssl-capath = "C:/vcerts"

[mysqld]
ssl-ca = "C:/vcerts/ca-cert.pem"
ssl-cert = "C:/vcerts/server-cert.pem"
ssl-key = "C:/vcerts/server-key.pem"
ssl
ssl-capath = "C:/vcerts"
```

At MySQL Workbench, after SSL Wizard's certificate generation, the SSL certificate settings are:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you restarted the MySQL server process after configuring SSL?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ MySQL service is down at the moment. The error appears when I'm trying to start the server. I tried reboot and a clean re-install but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by editing my.ini, step-by-step according to mySQL SLL setup documentation.
SSL settings inside my.ini should be:

```
[client]
ssl-ca=C:/vca/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=C:/vca/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=C:/vca/client-key.pem
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=C:/vca/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=C:/vca//server-cert.pem
ssl-key=C:/vca//server-key.pem
```

I guess the problem was that server understands "\s" (or "/s") as "space". So the last 2 server lines looked like:

```
ssl-cert=C:/vca/ erver-cert.pem
ssl-key=C:/vca/ erver-key.pem
```

According to server's logic. Plus configuration path/filename must be the same as windows service initialization path.

Configuration path/filename at mySQL Workbench:
[image]

Configuration path/filename at MySQL57 service:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL57
```